# GCD - is this solution iterative?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Using the property that GCD(a, b) = GCD(b, r) where r is the remainder when you compute (a / b), you can write a recursive function as follows:

```
(define (gcd a b)
  ; recursive
  (if (= 0 b) a
      (gcd b (remainder a b))))
```

I also tried to write the following as an iterative function, but it still looks very similar to the recursive solution to my eye.  Is this a correct, iterative solution?

```
(define (i-gcd a b)
  ; is this iterative?
  (i-gcd-iter (remainder a b) b))

(define (i-gcd-iter acc b)
  (if (= 0 b) acc
      (gcd b (remainder acc b))))
```

EDIT: It appears that the first solution was actually iterative, and in fact very similar to the solution written in SICP (http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html).  What would a recursive solution to this problem look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, both versions you have are iterative. I'm not actually sure that a recursive solution makes sense in this case---usually a recursive approach is for the classical pattern of holding the result of operating on the first item, then recursing into the remaining items. Calculating the GCD doesn't fit that pattern.

One small suggestion: you can use `(zero? b)` instead of `(= 0 b)`.

Comment: How is the first solution not recursive? It calls itself until the problem is solved, the passes the result up the call stack until the caller is reached.

Comment: @Michael: In Scheme, tail recursion is treated as iteration (and indeed, in Scheme, that's the _only_ way to do iteration; there is no `goto` facility). Therefore, Schemers treat tail recursion ("iteration") as a separate concept from non-tail recursion ("recursion").

Comment: (For readers unfamiliar with Scheme: all Scheme implementations are [required to implement "proper tail calls"](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.5), "tail call optimisation", or whatever you call it---again, because that's the only available method to implement iteration.)

Comment: So that (gcd) call essentially becomes (remainder), goto (if) ?

Comment: @Michael: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: @Chris I've seen the optimization in other languages, but didn't realize that it was always done in Scheme.

Comment: @Michael: \*nods\* Scheme provides other facilities for iteration (like `do`, `for-each`, etc.), but those are all macros or functions built on top of "named `let`", which is macro commonly used to create a recursive function that is then (in the case of `do`, `for-each`, etc.) called in tail position. :-)

Comment: @Chris good summary of tail-calling, but I would disagree with your claim that iterative recursion is not "recursion." A recursive procedure is one that calls itself, period. So OP's solution is both recursive and iterative. Minor point. Sorry.

Comment: @John - In SICP, they contrast "linear recursive process" against "iterative processes" (In context, an "iterative process" is a repetition that happens in constant space, where a "recursive process" builds up intermediate state [link here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1)).

Comment: @Inaimathi - It looks like SICP is careful, though, to distinguish "recursive processes" from "recursive procedures."

Comment: @John - Yup, but the word "recursive" shows up in both senses, so I've learned to expect this particular ambiguity. At first I assumed Chris made the distinction, but on second reading it's unclear whether he's talking about recursive processes or recursive functions; he uses the words "solution" and "approach", which could conceivably refer to either. I'm assuming he's referring to processes since the alternative wouldn't make sense. It could use clarification though.